# Apply function over columns of two matrices

Tags: r

```
dat1 = matrix(c("C", "T", "G", "G", "G", "G", "A", "A"), nrow=2, byrow=F)
dat2 = matrix(c("T", "C", "G", "G", "G/A", "G/A", "G", "A"), nrow=2, byrow=F)
```

I have these two matrices and I want to know if all elements of column 1 of matrix 1 are elements of column 1 of matrix 2, and so on for every column. Notice that I'm not using is.element() because it wouldn't work in the case of column 4, where I have a tolerated ambiguity (suggestions about this are welcome).

I'm doing this with a loop, but how can I avoid the loop using an apply function?

```
vec = logical(ncol(dat1))   

for(i in 1:ncol(dat1)) {
    vec[i] = all(rowSums(sapply(dat1[,i], grepl, dat2[,i]))>0)
}
```

Comment: use sapply to replace the `for(i...)` part: `sapply(1:ncol(dat1), function(i) all(rowSums(sapply(dat1[,i], grepl, dat2[,i]))>0))`

Comment: consider something like `setdiff(unique(dat1[,i]),unique(dat2[,i]))` ?

Comment: If you really wanted to do this with an `*apply` function (which will offer no advantages that I can think of)  you could convert to dataframes and then use `mapply`.

Comment: Your `rowSums` should be `colSums`. Try replacing your second `G/A` with `C` to test.

Answer (score 0):

I like rawr's solution. Thanks!

```
sapply(1:ncol(dat1), function(i) all(rowSums(sapply(dat1[,i], grepl, dat2[,i]))>0))
```